# How to use d3.time.scale() to generate an array of evenly spaced dates?

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, d3.js

This seems like it should be trivial. I want to use `d3.time.scale()` to get an array of evenly spaced dates that covers a certain range of time. For example, years

```
 [2012-01-01, 2013-01-01, 2014-01-01]
```

or months

```
 [2012-01-01, 2012-02-01, 2012-03-01 ... 2014-12-01]
```

or whatever.

So I start out like this:

```
var t = d3.time.scale()
    .domain(d3.extent(dates))
    .nice(d3.time.year);
```

I would then assume from the [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales#wiki-ticks) that I'd be able to do this

```
var ticks = t.ticks(d3.time.month,1);
```

...but that just returns a single date.

This gives me an array of months

```
var ticks = t.ticks(30)
```

...but only because I told it roughly how many ticks to generate (30), which I won't know in advance (unless I do some heavy lifting on my own, which kind of defeats the purpose of using d3 for this).

I don't understand why it's not working to just tell it that I want every year, or every month, or every 3 months, or whatever.

I've put up a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/herbcaudill/LgGpd/4/

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm not using this in conjunction with the axis object. I just want an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the Date() constructor doesn't work reliably -- it basically depends on the browser. It's much safer to parse explicitly. The constructor doesn't parse as such.

Instead of

```
var dates = getDates().map(function(d) { return new Date(d) });
```

use this:

```
var dates = getDates().map(function(d) {
    return d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse(d);
});
```

Modified jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LgGpd/5/).

Comment: The original fiddle link that I put up was wrong - can you take a look at the current one? http://jsfiddle.net/herbcaudill/LgGpd/4/

Comment: This works, although I'm not totally clear why. I was parsing the dates, but I was using `new Date(d)` while you used `d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse(d)`. As far as I can tell both create ordinary `Date` objects but yours have the time zeroed out while mine return the time expressed in my local time zone. I'm not sure (a) why the dates are being parsed differently, or (b) why this makes such a difference to d3.

Comment: Using the `Date()` constructor doesn't work reliably -- it basically depends on the browser. It's much safer to parse explicitly. The constructor doesn't parse as such.

Comment: OK - I'll edit your answer to make that clear if you don't mind.

Answer (score 2):

Using a dataset such as

```
var dataset = [ 
      { "active" : false,
        "date" : "2014-12-12"
      },
      { "active" : true,
        "date" : "2014-12-13"
      },
      { "active" : true,
        "date" : "2014-12-14"
      },
      { "active" : true,
        "date" : "2014-12-15"
      }
    ]

var slicedData = var slicedData = dataset.slice();
```

I had a similar problem, and found that

```
var x = d3.time.scale()
    .domain([new Date(slicedData[0].date), new Date(slicedData[slicedData.length - 1].date)])
    .range([0,width]);
```

Dropped the first item in the scale (it still remains a mystery as to why that was the case), whereas

```
var dates = slicedData.map(function(d) {
        return d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse(d.date);
    });
    var t = d3.time.scale()
        .domain(d3.extent(dates))
        .range([0,width])
        .nice(d3.time.day);
```

worked fine.

So, my only explanation is the one Lars provided. Date() is unpredictable, so use d3.time.format instead.