# D3 Stacked bar chart

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Hi I have created a vertical stacked bar chart . My data is in csv file. My x scale is ordinal.AS per the requirement my x scale should me time scale. what changes should I make to make my x axis time scale. I have only limited time to complete this. Here is my code

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
     .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);


var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x).ticks(5)
    .orient("bottom");
```

Comment: Try a time scale, like var x = d3.time.scale().domain(d3.extent(dates))  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181286/how-to-use-d3-time-scale-to-generate-an-array-of-evenly-spaced-dates

Comment: The other option is to continue to use an ordinal scale, but define the domain of the scale by creating an array of all dates using a [d3.time.interval range function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Intervals#wiki-interval_range).  Then use a date formatting function as the axis tick format function.  The difference between this approach and the one suggested by @Maggie is that, with a true time scale, unevenly spaced date units (e.g. months, which can have different numbers of days), while be uneven widths.  With an ordinal scale, they will all be drawn to the same width.

Comment: Say, @AmeilaBR, your explanation inadvertently solved a problem for me before I posted it.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response. But I can not use a specify domain as my data comes dynamically. I want to change the code in such a way that the data comes dynamically. I used CSV file for the time being only. I can not hard code the array with some specific date values. Please suggest a solution ASAP.

Answer (score 2):

put here your CSV structure.
most probably your solution is

```
 parse = d3.time.format("%H:%M:%S").parse,
 format = d3.time.format("%X");
```

where in your CSV file time column shoud be like : 'hour:minute:second' format.

and pass 'format' value on your axis

for precise answer put your code here!
or else you can [refer this](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting)

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much for all the responses on time.

Comment: have you got successful solution?

Comment: Yes had to change the time scale and lot of changes and now its working with static data. need to change to dynamic.I hope converting CSV to JSON is not a tough job. Is it?

Comment: CSV to Json is too simple. Keep in mind that CSV follows column structure where as JSON follows 'key' and it's 'value'. If can help you if you need. Just provide your sample data.

Comment: JSON row: {"date":"1/5/2014","allocated":"14.14","unallocated":"7.14"} and csv file: date,allocated,unallocated(val1,val2,val3)