# d3 - transform x scale from first start date to last end date

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have a simple question about the `d3.time.scale()`. I have the following code:

```
var xScale = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, w - margin.left - margin.right])
    .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.startDate; })); // this is wrong
```

and a sample `.json` data:

```
{
    "name":"Mark",
    "startDate":"4-Oct-1992", // make this first date in scale
    "endDate":"6-Oct-1992",

},
{
    "name":"Bill",
    "startDate":"17-Dec-1992",
    "endDate":"20-Dec-1992",
}
{
    "name":"Steve",
    "startDate":"17-Jan-1993",
    "endDate":"20-Jan-1993" // make this last date in scale
}
```

Basically would like to change the `.domain` to go from the first `startDate` to the last `endDate` on the set of data.

If this isn't possible, another solution would be to set each dates manually. i.e. the ff code to add to the `json`:

```
{
    "name":"Mark",
    "startDate":"4-Oct-1992", 
    "endDate":"6-Oct-1992",
    "scale":"1-Jan-1992" // first date      
},
{
    "name":"Bill",
    "startDate":"17-Dec-1992",
    "endDate":"20-Dec-1992",
}
{
    "name":"Steve",
    "startDate":"17-Jan-1993",
    "endDate":"20-Jan-1993" 
    "scale":"31-Dec-1993" // last date
}

.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.scale; }));
```

<strike>(I'll actually try that one though right now to see if it works)
Edit: Apparently it doesn't work and I get `TypeError: string is undefined`.</strike>

I did remember to parse the date  inside a `forEach` function to make it readable: `d.scale = parseDate(d.scale);` but why doesn't it work still?

I added an empty `"scale":""` to every other data and that now works!

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to achieve... what should be the domain? `[min(startDate), max(endDate)]`, `[data[0].startDate, data[data.length-1].endDate]`?

Comment: You need to parse the strings into Date objects for the time scale to work, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181286/how-to-use-d3-time-scale-to-generate-an-array-of-evenly-spaced-dates

Comment: yes I have parsed the strings into Date objects. I'd like the x axis to go from the first `startDate` of all the data to the last `endDate`. In my code above it uses `d3.extent` for `startDate` so that obviously is wrong.   `[min(startDate), max(endDate)]` seems to be it from the looks of it